# Avoiding code repetition in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I find that this happens too often in Verilog code:

```
wire my_module_output_1;
wire my_module_output_2;
wire my_module_output_3;
...

MyModule my_module(
    .output_1(my_module_output_1),
    .output_2(my_module_output_2),
    .output_3(my_module_output_3),
    ...
);

MyOtherModule my_other_module(
    .input_1(my_module_output_1),
    .input_2(my_module_output_2),
    .input_3(my_module_output_3),
    ...
);
```

What I **wish** I could do is:

```
MyModule my_module();
MyOtherModule my_other_module(
    .input_1(my_module.output_1),
    .input_2(my_module.output_2),
    .input_3(my_module.output_3),
    ...
);
```

Is there any such way for me to achieve the same effect, i.e. to avoid having to repeat myself over and over again every time I need an output from some module wired somewhere?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the example, is there a reason you don't just connect 'some_other_wire' directly to the output port to achieve the same result: `.output_1(some_other_wire_1)`

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, let me change the example... the point is that it's not always possible to do that, e.g. if instead of `some_other_wire_1` it's the input of another module, or if you need to be inside an `always` block, etc.

Comment: @Tim: Fixed, does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Unfortunately for you I don't think such a thing exists. The verilog standard does support hierarchical references which allow you to connect directly to wires inside a module without an existing port, but I believe that most synthesizers don't support it and as a coding style I think it's generally frowned upon.

Comment: Is this for synthesis? Your second example is valid code.

Comment: @Adam12: Yes, it's for synthesis... it didn't seem to be valid when I tried it, is it just valid for simulation?

Comment: SystemVerilog interface can come close to this, but they are a real pain to debug, no hierarchy to trace, no idea which module is actually driving the values. Agree with @Tim that this would tend to be frowned upon.

Comment: @Morgan: Driving an *internal* wire is indeed a bad idea, I agree -- that's something I never intended to do. But why would simply connecting two input/output ports like that be frowned upon? Isn't that their entire purpose?

Comment: @Mehrdad expert techniques like this tend to be avoided, partly so everyone can understand the code, it might effect the ability to debug, and commercial tools are pretty slow to support new features. You could spend months developing with your front end tools (compiler simulator) to realise that your back end tools (synthesis) do not support the syntax and you quickly have to rewire your entire design.

Comment: If it is a repetitive structure generate statements might work, or a pearl, ruby pre processed template, less lines of code is less bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few approaches you can use to reduce the amount of repetition.

### The starting point

Here's a simple example that connects two sub-modules.  As you noted in your question, there is a lot of repetition required to stitch them together.

```
module source(output A, output B);
  assign A = 0;
  assign B = 1;
endmodule

module sink(input A, input B);
  initial begin
    #1 $display("A=%0d B=%0d", A, B);
  end
endmodule

module top();

  wire A;
  wire B;

  source the_source(
    .A(A),
    .B(B)
  );

  sink the_sink(
    .A(A),
    .B(B)
  );

endmodule
```

---

### Using implicit wires

Verilog allows for wires to be declared implicitly. So, as shown below, you don't need to declare `A` and `B` as wires. If they appear in a port map, they will be implicitly declared. The only problem with this is that they are always declared as single-bit wires/nets. So while this works fine for single-bit signals, for buses the interconnect still needs to be explicitly declared.

```
// Verilog, implicit wires
module top();

source the_source(
  .A(A),
  .B(B)
);

sink the_sink(
  .A(A),
  .B(B)
);

endmodule
```

---

### Using Verilog-Mode AUTOs

The [Verilog-Mode emacs package](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode) can help tremendously in reducing the amount of typing required to stitch modules together. Here is the example from above using AUTOs.

Before expanding the AUTOs:

```
// Verilog, explicit connections using AUTOs
module top();

  /*AUTOWIRE*/

  source the_source (/*AUTOINST*/);

  sink the_sink (/*AUTOINST*/);

endmodule
```

After expanding the AUTOs:

```
// Verilog, explicit using AUTOs
module top();

  /*AUTOWIRE*/
  // Beginning of automatic wires (for undeclared instantiated-module outputs)
  wire                A;                      // From the_source of source.v
  wire                B;                      // From the_source of source.v
  // End of automatics

  source the_source (/*AUTOINST*/
                     // Outputs
                     .A               (A),
                     .B               (B));

  sink the_sink (/*AUTOINST*/
                 // Inputs
                 .A                   (A),
                 .B                   (B));

endmodule
```

As Brian pointed out in his answer, you don't need to use emacs to use Verilog-Mode. I also use Vim and use [this Vim script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1875) to enable Verilog-Mode from within Vim.

---

### SystemVerilog option

If you can use SystemVerilog, you can use the dot-star notation to connect ports by names.  This is pretty handy but you still have to declare the wires for interconnects between peer modules.

```
// SystemVerilog, dot-star notation
module top();

  wire A;
  wire B;

  source the_source(.*);
  sink the_sink(.*);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Are people still not using Verilog AUTOs everywhere?

http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode/Verilog-mode-Help

In particular pay attention to the section on AUTOINST.  This isn't going to solve all your problems but judicious use of AUTOs takes a lot of the tedium out of generating structural Verilog.

Don't mind that it's an Emacs node.  I'm a vim guy myself but I just pipe my buffer through emacs with this mode loaded when I need my AUTOs updated.

Comment: Ah, I don't use emacs. +1 though.